how to get the last row in cell in excel

I need help to get the last line of a cell that has 10 lines in excel.
Which means ı have 10 line in a single excel line and need to  copy the last line(After pressing ALT+Enter) and paste to a different excel cell.
Basically, extract the last line from a cell containing multiple lines separated by ALT+Enter.

Assuming no Excel Constraints as per the tags posted then the following formula should work as per your post explanations:


=TAKE(TEXTSPLIT(A1,,CHAR(10)),-1)


Or, Using FILTERXML()
=FILTERXML("<m><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),"</b><b>")&"</b></m>","//b[last()]")


Or for older versions:
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),REPT(" ",100)),100))


Or Using TEXTAFTER()
=TEXTAFTER(A1,CHAR(10),-1)



Another alternative is;
=RIGHT(A1;LEN(A1)-FIND("@";SUBSTITUTE(A1;CHAR(10);"@";LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1;CHAR(10);"")));1))

